# LINQ to List<KeyValuePair>

Tags: c#, linq, keyvaluepair

I'm currently working on an .NET Framework 4.7.2 application. I'm working on a LINQ query selecting objects from the given data structure:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, object>>>
```

It is a list of dynamic objects. I need to select all elements from the list, where the **value** in the dictionary is **true**, the key would be IsDummy in this case.

The following image shows the data structure *xyz* in debug mode:

[image]

```
var result = xyz
    .Select(a => a.Value)
    .SelectMany(b => b)
    .Where(c => c.Key == "IsDummy" && (bool)c.Value == true);
```

I would like to select a `List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, object>>>` where the value object in the dictionary is of type boolean and has the value true.

Unfortunately my current query doesn't work correctly.

Do you know how to solve this LINQ query? It is a bit tricky because of the KeyValuePair and Dictionary within the list.

Thank you very much!

Comment: There is no LINQ query to solve. What have you got so far?

Comment: that's how the data comes in... i cannot change that unfortunately...

Comment: What exactly do you want to select? a `KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, object>>` where the dictionary has a key `"IsDummy"` and an `object` of `true`? or the respective `int`? or the dictionary?

Comment: thank you for consideration!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
var result = xyz
    .Where(kv => kv.Value.TryGetValue("IsDummy", out object value) 
                 && value is bool b && b); // pattern matching C#7
```

Non C#7 version:

```
...
&& value is bool && (bool)value);
```

Comment: Great solution Tim, thank you! I need to look more into C#7 pattern matching. :)

Answer (score 1):

You specified:

> I would like to select a `List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string,
>   object>>>` where **the value object in the dictionary** is of type boolean
>   and has the value true.

**The** value object? Does this mean that all Dictionaries in the list have only one Value?

- Or do you only want those elements from your list that have a Dictionary that has only one value: a Boolean that is true?
- Or do you only want those elements from your list that have a Dictionary with at least one Boolean value true?
- Or maybe all values should be Booleans with true value?

.

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, object>>> source = ...
var result = source
    // keep only those items in the list that have a Dictionary with only one value,
    // namely a Boolean that is true
    .Where(pair => pair.Value.Count == 1 
                // pair.Value is a Dictionary; 
                // pair.Value.Values are the values in the Dictionary
                // only keep this item if the one and only value in the dictionary is a Boolean with a value true
                && pair.Value.Values.First().GetType() == typeof(bool)
                && (bool)pair.Value.ValuesFirst());
```

This can be optimized, using this you'll enumerate the dictionary twice. I leave it like this for improved readability.

2nd specification: Keep only those elements from the list that have a Dictionary that has at least one Boolean with a true value

```
var result = source
    .Where(pair => pair.Value.Values
         // keep only the values in the dictionary that are Boolean:
         .OfType<bool>()
         // keep only the true values
         .Where(dictionaryValue => dictionaryValue)
         // keep this list item if there is at least one such value in the dictionary
         .Any());
```

With these examples, it will be easy to code the version where all items in the dictionary must be Booleans with a true value